# Confusion regarding definition of path in Graph theory

Tags: path, graph-theory

I am having confusion regarding the definition of path.

In wikipedia the definition of path is given as follows

A path is a trail in which all vertices (except possibly the first and last) are distinct.

[Definition of path in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Definitions)

But what I knew was

A path is a trail in which all vertices are distinct.

Please tell me which one is the correct definition of Path.

Comment: Wikipedia's definition allows for closed paths, yours does not. They don't agree with each other, but it's not clear whether one is right or wrong. That's the beauty of definitions: Everyone can have their own.

Comment: Closed path is a cycle isn't it? Then according to the definition in wikipedia a cycle is also becoming a path. Is the statement all cycles are path correct?

Comment: Under the definition in Wikipedia, yes. Note that the article states that different authors use different definitions, so for any reasoning about paths you must state which definition you use.